# React Native: error while updating property src of a view managed by RCTImageView

Tags: react-native, expo

this one has been asked a bit here and around the web, but it seems every case is different. On a brand new Expo app, I can reliably crash it **on Android** (iOS is fine) with the following code:

```js
export default function App() {
    const imageSource: ImageSourcePropType = [
        {
            scale: 1,
            uri: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/flwc-app-media/audio-speakers/2022-08/jessie.png?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=nodejs-api%40flwc-production.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20220916%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220916T104214Z&X-Goog-Expires=1800&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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',
        },
        {
            scale: 2,
            uri: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/flwc-app-media/audio-speakers/2022-08/jessie%402x.png?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=nodejs-api%40flwc-production.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20220916%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220916T104214Z&X-Goog-Expires=1800&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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',
        },
        {
            scale: 3,
            uri: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/flwc-app-media/audio-speakers/2022-08/jessie%403x.png?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=nodejs-api%40flwc-production.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20220916%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220916T104214Z&X-Goog-Expires=1800&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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',
        },
    ]

    return <Image source={imageSource} />
}
```

If passing a single-element array as `ImageSourcePropType`, then the crash won't happen. So, specifically on Android, a multi-element array as image source makes the app crash.

Any clue what it could be?

Comment: hey i cant repro the crash, can you share an expo snack? will check there

Comment: [I've a repo](https://github.com/flowchase/break-image-component), this tiny example crashes on Android, on both the emulator and a Pixel 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: [I've filled a React Native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34711), and was told this is the intended behavior, as `width` and `height` are required when loading files from the network. I'm not sure why the single-element array doesn't cause a crash, nor why this used to work just fine under React Native 0.65, but the solution is to specific the dimensions of each image. Note that on iOS this works fine even without image dimensions.